# Performance issues using SSIS Unpivot component

Tags: ssis, etl

I am using SSIS and have the need for Unpivoting 60+ columns.
This is causing extreme performance issues, is there a way to tune this to increase performance? Anyone that knows the best practice for this?

Im already following Microsoft Performance Tuning Techniques, like auto adjust buffer size etc.

Performance issues are related to unpivoting components. The data is coming from and MSSQL server (OLEDB Source). The destination is the same as the server (different database) and uses OLEDB(fast load). Mainly string and GUID data types involved, some int's and datetime, but not in the unpivoting part. We are speaking 300 columns with string data and 600 columns that are just generated GUID's (NEWID()). The input amount is about 130 000 rows, the output, after unpivoting is about 18 000 000. I unpivot about 850 of the columns into 70 new destination columns. (70 different destination columns, 12 input columns to each).

Comment: What sort of performance issues are you encountering? Where is the data coming from, where are you landing it, what data types are involved, how many columns, how many rows and can you show what your data flow looks like and specifically what the unpivot looks like?